# how to minimize youtubeplay like as youtube in right corner of screen in an application?

Tags: android

I have implemented `'com.github.pedrovgs:draggablepanel:1.9'`in gradle version 3.1.3

but getting below error

```
 inflating class com.guithub.pedrovgs.DraggableView
```

Don't know what I have to do. Please help me